# Dramatiq worker and socketio

Tags: python, flask-socketio, dramatiq

I have a Flask web service that has to do a long async operation in the background and needs to notify the client when it completes.

To do this, I use `dramatiq` to run the async task and `flask_socketio` to use websockets to notify the client.

My code looks like this:

```
import dramatiq
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from engineio.payload import Payload

Payload.max_decode_packets = 500

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

async_mode = "eventlet"

socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('document.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    socketio.emit('my_response', {'data': 'First emit'}, namespace='/test') 

    act.send()

    return { "result": "success" }

@dramatiq.actor
def act():
    # some long operation goes in here
    socketio.emit('my_response', {'data': 'Second Emit'}, namespace='/test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

The first emit works and the second one does not. This is hardly surprising, considering the second emit is actually being executed by a worker in a separate process.

How do I modify my code to make it work? I thought and tried `callbacks` but they are also `actors`, so do difference there... Any other ideas?

Comment: Is dramatiq compatible with eventlet?